# Why is the state changing by itself in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**What I'm Trying to do**: I have the following react component, which is chat box, which toggles to view on clicking a button. The chatBox will be opened or closed according the value in the state 'open'. When the user clicks on the chat button, the function 'toggleChat' is run, which just toggles the value of 'open' state between true and false.

**Problem**: Now the problem is, when a new message is received, I am trying to keep the count of unread messages, if the chatBox isn't 'opened'.  But it fails. In my opinion it should work, but the 'open' state is not what I expect it to be sometimes. Sometimes, even though the chatBox is opened, the open state inside is 'false'.

**Minified Code**

```
export default function Chat (props) { 
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [unreadMsgs, setUnreadMsgs] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('join', uuid);
        socket.on('newMsg', msg => {
            setMsgArr(prevMsgArr => [ ...prevMsgArr, { type: 'received', msg }]);
            if(!open) setUnreadMsgs(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
        });
    }, []);

    const toggleChat = () => {
        if(open) setOpen(false);
        else {
            setOpen(true);
            setUnreadMsgs(0);
        }
    }
```

**Entire code**

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import FiberManualRecordIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FiberManualRecord';

const socket = io('http://127.1.1.1:4000');

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    paper : {
        height : 300,
    },
    list : {
        height : '100%',
        boxSizing : 'border-box',
    },
    chatContainer : {
        position : 'relative',
        height : '95%',
        width : 300,
    },
    chatBox : {
        height : '82%',
        position : 'absolute',
        top : '8%',
        width : '100%',
        overflowY : 'auto',
    },
    msgForm : {
        width : '100%',
        padding : 10,
        position : 'absolute',
        bottom : 0,
        height : '6%',
        textAlign : 'center',
    },
    anchor : {
        top : 7,
    },
    badge : {
        background : '#007eff',
    },
});

export default function Chat (props) { 
    const uuid = props.uuid;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [activeStatus, setActiveStatus] = useState('Offline');
    const [msgArr, setMsgArr] = useState([]);
    const chatBtnRef = useRef();
    const chatBoxRef = useRef();
    const msgInputRef = useRef();
    //working on showing count of unread messages
    const [unreadMsgs, setUnreadMsgs] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('join', uuid);
        socket.on('newMsg', msg => {
            setMsgArr(prevMsgArr => [ ...prevMsgArr, { type: 'received', msg }]);
            setTimeout(() => {
                chatBoxRef.current.scrollTop = chatBoxRef.current.scrollHeight; 
            }, 50);
            console.log(open);
            if(!open) setUnreadMsgs(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
        });
        if(props.isReceiver) {
            socket.emit('isReceiverOnline', uuid);
            socket.on('isSenderOnline', () => {
                setActiveStatus('Online');
            });
        } else {
            socket.emit('isSenderOnline', uuid);
            socket.on('isReceiverOnline', () => {
                setActiveStatus('Online');
                socket.emit('isSenderOnline', uuid);
            });
        }
        socket.on("isOffline", () => {
            setActiveStatus('Offline');
        });
        return () => {
            socket.off('isOffline');
            socket.off('newMsg');
            socket.off('isOnline');
        }
    }, []);

    const handleMsgSend = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let msg = msgInputRef.current.value;
        setMsgArr([ ...msgArr, { type: 'sent', msg }]);
        e.currentTarget.reset();
        socket.emit('newMsg', {uuid,  msg});
        setTimeout(() => chatBoxRef.current.scrollTop = chatBoxRef.current.scrollHeight, 50);
    }

    const toggleChat = () => {
        if(open) setOpen(false);
        else {
            setOpen(true);
            setUnreadMsgs(0);
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
        <Tooltip title={ `${activeStatus}` }>
            <IconButton>
                <FiberManualRecordIcon style={{ height : 14, width : 14, fill : (activeStatus == "Offline")? '#00000057' : 'rgb(136 210 130)'}}/>
            </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip title={ `${unreadMsgs}  unread messages` }>
                <IconButton ref={chatBtnRef} onClick={ toggleChat }>
                    <MailIcon style={{ fill:'white' }}/>
                </IconButton>      
        </Tooltip>
        <Menu
            classes={{ paper : classes.paper, list : classes.list}}
            anchorEl={chatBtnRef.current}
            keepMounted
            open={ open }
        >   
            <div style={{ position : 'relative', zIndex : '1', height : '5%', textAlign:'right'}}>
                <IconButton onClick={ toggleChat }>
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.chatContainer}>
                <div ref={ chatBoxRef } className={ classes.chatBox }>
                    {
                        msgArr.map((msgObj, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index} className={`msg-container ${(msgObj.type == 'sent')? 'myMsg' : 'hisMsg'}`}>
                                    <span className='msg'>
                                        { msgObj.msg }
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }                     
                </div>
                <form className={ classes.msgForm } onSubmit={ handleMsgSend }>
                    <input
                        style ={{
                            padding : 3,
                            fontSize : 14,
                            borderRadius : 3,
                            width : 250
                        }}
                        ref={msgInputRef} type="text" 
                        className={classes.msgInput} 
                        placeholder="Type your Msg here."/>
                </form>
            </div>
      </Menu>
      </>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you add the JSX too ?

Comment: `open` inside `useEffect` with `[]` is a stale state i.e. a value from the first render. You cannot rely on it. It will always be the one that got set during the first render and post that the function inside `useEffect` closed over it.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I thought that too, but then I have chatMsgs state, which I change inside the function of useEffect. It doesn't use the value from the first render. I've added the entire code that I'm using. I've been stuck at this for days, please help me.

Comment: @Codenewbie I have included it.

Comment: You don't seem to have `msgArr` state directly in the `useEffect` in your code. You are instead using the `prevMsgArr` which is available  inside the `setMsgArr` callback as a parameter. That `prevMsgArr` isn't affected by closures.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur, how about using a `useCallback` to create the `newMsg` callback that depends on open state, then insert the callback dependency in `useEffect`

Comment: @LakshyaThakur what do you mean by 'not affected by closures'.

Comment: @nikeshlepz It's always the latest value given to you by the **state updator function** which is `setMsgArr` for you. And the closure bit is same as what I stated for `open` in my first comment.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Oh, thanks now I get it. I'm very new to react, and don't know the very basic things of how the hell it works. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the dependencies to useEffect that are used in the function.

Also add `const [msgArr, setMsgArr] = useState([]);` if it is not there.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.emit('join', uuid);
}, []); // you can pass socket here as it's not going to change

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("newMsg", (msg) => {
    setMsgArr((prevMsgArr) => [...prevMsgArr, { type: "received", msg }]);
    if (!open) setUnreadMsgs((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  });

  return () => socket.removeAllListeners("newMsg"); // remove earlier registered handlers
}, [open]);
```

Updated the De-registration of the event handler if a dependency changes. (based on comment discussion and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073527/8915198)

Comment: Does this cause one more additional socket handler to be registered or automatically causes the last `socket.on` one to be unregistered and new one to registered ?

Comment: Sorry but unreadMsgs is to store the count of unread messages. And your thing worked for me.

Comment: I'm gonna try and look more on dependencies of useEffect. :)

Comment: @LakshyaThakur, IMO, As we have an event name "newMsg", it will be going to replace the older function with new.

Comment: @nikeshlepz Add ESLint and it will show you missed useEffect dependencies.

Comment: No multiple event handlers will be attached, which will eventually cause node to throw the maxListenersExceeded warning. That's why I have a cleanup function returned by the useEffect function which gets called everytime the dependency (in this case 'open') changes.

Comment: @nikeshlepz I hope you're doing something like stated in my answer.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I just put open in my dependency of useEffect, and voila, it works all of a sudden.

Comment: @nikeshlepz But what about removing the existing listener ? I think that's an additional step you would have to do in your cleanup function like I did.

Comment: Yes, @LakshyaThakur, I think, your answer is correct. I will update mine with credit. Do suggest nikesh to mark yours as an accepted answer.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I;m gonna give this one to Dhaval, since he is new to the community, and will help him earn reputation(he deserves it here). But yea, I get what you're talking about, and I added another useEffect just as you have suggested.

Comment: @nikeshlepz I am okay with that . Just wanted to let you have the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Already given the explanation for `closures` in the comments but the working solution for you should look something like below :-

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.emit('join', uuid);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {

  function getNewMsg(msg){
    setMsgArr((prevMsgArr) => [...prevMsgArr, { type: "received", msg }]);
    if (!open) setUnreadMsgs((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  }

  socket.on("newMsg",getNewMsg)

  return ()=>socket.removeListener("newMsg",getNewMsg);
}, [open]);
```

Basically the **cleanup** step I think is necessary as you do with major **event paradigms**.